# Ideas for creating a footer and subfooter using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi all and thanks in advance for any guidance.

So here's what I'm trying to do. I have a fixed position div (#div_1) that sits at the bottom of a long page and is the pages footer...until the user scrolls all the way the bottom...then there's a sub footer (#div_2) should appear directly below #div_1. I've searched around and can't find exactly the solution I need.

Again, any help is appreciated.

Comment: How far did you get? Can you make a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) of the work you've done so far?

Comment: You generally shouldn't search around for stuff like this - you figure it out and built it yourself by dividing the task at hand (you need a way to get the scroll position and a way of displaying/hiding an HTML element). Otherwise you'll be stuck again at the next trivial feature.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the #div_2, and fadeIn() or show() it when user scrolls to the bottom of the page. Use the follow function to detect if user scrolls to bottom:

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
   if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
       $('#div_2').fadeIn();
   } else {
      //code
  }
});
```

Comment: the scroll event fires a lot and can cause buts you should use a set timeout to re initialize it, see here from this blog post http://ejohn.org/blog/learning-from-twitter/

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I'm just keeping #div_2 hidden behind #div_1 until the user reaches the bottom of the page and then bumping the bottom on #div_1 up by x pixels to show the subfooter (#div_2)

**CSS**

```
#div_2{width:100%;height:50px; background:green;position:fixed;bottom:0; z-index:1}
#div_1{width:100%;height:95px; background:red; position:fixed; bottom:0; z-index:2}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
   if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
       $("#div_1").css('bottom','50px');
   }else{
       $("#div_1").css('bottom','0');
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should take care of the excess dom events:
If you want to read more about the issues check here http://ejohn.org/blog/learning-from-twitter

```
function footer() {
    //do this in case you already are at the bottom and miss the event
    showfooter();
    $(window).one('scroll', function() {
        showfooter()
        setTimeout(showfooter, 200);
    });
}
function showfooter() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
         $('#div_2').fadeIn();
    }
}
```